# Getting a public event by id (Upcoming)

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

I know the id of a public yql event. Why can't I get it by simply mentioning the id in WHERE clause like this:

[Click here to see my yql console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20upcoming.events%20WHERE%20id%20=%20%229236524%22%20%7C%20sort%28field=%27start_date%27%29%20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close - instead of `id` you'll want to use the parameter `event_id`. Here's a modified version of your search which works:

[`SELECT * FROM upcoming.events WHERE event_id = "9236524" | sort(field='start_date')`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20upcoming.events%20WHERE%20event_id%20%3D%20%229236524%22%20%7C%20sort%28field%3D%27start_date%27%29%20)

For Community YQL tables like `upcoming.events`, you can see the allowed parameters by clicking on the "desc" link on the far right. In this case it shows that searching by `event_id` is one of the options:

```
<select>
    <key name="event_id" required="true" type="xs:string"/>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. But in the returned JSon it has **"id": "9236524",** not **"event_id": "9236524",**. This is so confusing :(. In query the attribute name is id and in result the attribute name is event_id.